# wro4j CSS Lint Adding Custom Rules

Tags: jslint, wro4j, csslint

Our team wants to use the wro4j tool, and we have gotten it setup and able to run the csslint and jslint. We would like to create our own custom CSS rules, but we can't find any documentation on where the csslint rules are stored and how to create our own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add csslint rules, you should update configuration options section of the maven plugin:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupid>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupid>
    <artifactid>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactid>
    <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>csslint</goal>
    </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <options>box-model</options>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

More details are [documented here](http://wro4j.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.x/MavenPluginCssLint/).

**Update**:
The rules are defined by [csslint](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint) library (version 0.9.10). All the rules defined in the library can be referred in the configuration section of the maven plugin. Adding custom rule is not supported out of the box, if you need this feature, feel free to [create a feature request](https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j/issues/).

Comment: Yes, we understand how to add pre-made CSS rules to our pom file for the csslint to use, but we want to know **where these CSS rules are located and how we can create our own custom css rules**.